# Pivot table like data table from SharePoint 2016 list

Tags: data

do not know if this is possible as i have tried to find the solution doing some search. maybe asking the wrong question in my search.

try to create a data table much to the looks of a excel pivot table just not using excel.  if there is a html code, script content code or something else that would be great.  i am a basic novice when it comes to typing code.

here are some of the fields:

N-1              current step             on-time/late
con               step 2                    0
eng               step 3                    0 
con               step 2                    0

turn that into this

N-1              current step             on-time/late 
con                 2                        2
eng                 1                        1

any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the below steps:

Create a pivot table and pie chart from SharePoint list data

- Click anywhere in the table and then on 'Summarize with PivotTable'
  under the DESIGN tab in the Excel ribbon.
- Select what data you want to view in the Pivot table. Peter chooses the default option, the table he had clicked in.
- Drag and drop the fields you want to work with to some of the four Pivot areas.
- To create a chart, click in the Pivot table and then on the PivotChart button under the PIVOTTABLE TOOLS, ANALYZE tab.
- Select the chart type and design you prefer to visualize the data from the SharePoint list.

For the details implementation, you can refer the below article which has video also :

[Analyze List Data with Pivot Table and Chart](https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/HelpDesk-PivotTable-Chart.htm)

**Alternative coding approach :**

The same above pivot table can be implemented using VBA macro coding, please watch the below video how to implement this.

https://youtu.be/--wwfCFexKI